# Local SSH connection using private network IP address not working

Tags: networking, ssh

I tried to ssh connect to the local machine itself as

```
ssh me@host -p 2222
```

It prompt password to login

However, if attempt with

```
    $ ssh me@192.168.31.127 -p 2222
    ssh: connect to host 192.168.31.127 port 2222: No route to host


the ip address:

    $ ssh me@192.168.31.127 -p 2222
    ssh: connect to host 192.168.31.127 port 2222: No route to host
```

the localhost `127.0.0.1` works

```
$ ssh me@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
The authenticity of host '[127.0.0.1]:2222 ([127.0.0.1]:2222)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:rWQnXUO8mSlXRgNN4Jp1HMNqIO6K7WBO3EAihzvc3Es.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2222' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
***************************************************************************
                            NOTICE TO USERS
```

What's the problem?

Comment: If you are using anything other than a 127.0.0.1 IP Address, it will be going to the network and back. Something is blocking that port. 127.0.0.1 will normally work unless you have some funky firewall/iptables rules.

Comment: Please also note that "192.168.x.x" is not a "global" public IP address but a [private address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) inside your local network. It is not reachable over the internet and gets only routed within your own (home) network.

Comment: Please try using 127.0.0.1 and update your question with the results.

Comment: thank you, I updated the question. I tested the public address, cos I planned to access my machine from my mobile phone. @NGRhodes

Comment: `$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive` @user68186

Comment: Apologies if these questions are a little basic, but it's worth ruling the simple stuff out first.
Are both devices on the same local IP network (i.e. both have IP addresses in the range 192.168.31.1-254)? For the reason @ByteCommander, I will assume that you are. 
Is the SSH server listening to port 2222 on the external interface and not just the localhost loopback? `netstat -t` is your friend here, I would expect to see `0.0.0.0:ssh` in the response.
What happens when you ping or port scan (`nmap 192.168.31.127 -p 22, 2222`) your SSH server?